# Hi, I want to use the message filter in this example , I tried to register callback from a class member function as in the following code:

Tags: roscpp, ros-kinetic, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>

using namespace nav_msgs;
using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

class Data{

        public:
                void callback(const OdometryConstPtr& msg, const LaserScanConstPtr& dat);

        };

void Data::callback(const OdometryConstPtr& msg, const LaserScanConstPtr& dat){
        //pos1 = msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){

        ros::init(argc, argv, "odome");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;

        message_filters::Subscriber<Odometry> odometria(nh, "/odom", 1);
        message_filters::Subscriber<LaserScan> laser(nh, "/scan", 1);

        Data data;

        TimeSynchronizer<Odometry, LaserScan> sync(odometria, laser, 10);
        sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&Data::callback, &data,_1,_2));

        ros::spin();
        return 0;
}
```

and this its the error that show, sorry it's so long.

```
cd /home/juan/catkin_ws/build/gps_pos && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/src/prueba.cpp.o  -o /home/juan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gps_pos/prueba -rdynamic /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_filesystem -lboost_signals /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librostime.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lboost_atomic -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/kinetic/lib 
CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/src/prueba.cpp.o: En la función `message_filters::Connection message_filters::Signal9<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>::addCallback<boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&>(boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&)> const&)':
prueba.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters7Signal9IN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_IS3_EENS_8NullTypeES8_S8_S8_S8_S8_S8_E11addCallbackIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKS4_EERKNSC_IKS7_EERKNSC_IKS8_EESO_SO_SO_SO_SO_SO_EENS_10ConnectionERKNSB_8functionIFvT_T0_T1_T2_T3_T4_T5_T6_T7_EEE[_ZN15message_filters7Signal9IN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_IS3_EENS_8NullTypeES8_S8_S8_S8_S8_S8_E11addCallbackIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKS4_EERKNSC_IKS7_EERKNSC_IKS8_EESO_SO_SO_SO_SO_SO_EENS_10ConnectionERKNSB_8functionIFvT_T0_T1_T2_T3_T4_T5_T6_T7_EEE]+0x4d2): referencia a `message_filters::Connection::Connection(boost::function<void ()> const&)' sin definir
CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/src/prueba.cpp.o: En la función `message_filters::Synchronizer<message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::~Synchronizer()':
prueba.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SynchronizerINS_13sync_policies9ExactTimeIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_IS5_EENS_8NullTypeESA_SA_SA_SA_SA_SA_EEED2Ev[_ZN15message_filters12SynchronizerINS_13sync_policies9ExactTimeIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_IS5_EENS_8NullTypeESA_SA_SA_SA_SA_SA_EEED5Ev]+0x28): referencia a `message_filters::Connection::disconnect()' sin definir
CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/src/prueba.cpp.o: En la función `message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >::registerCallback<ros::MessageEvent<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>(boost::function<void (ros::MessageEvent<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&)':
prueba.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SimpleFilterIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEE16registerCallbackIRKN3ros12MessageEventIKS4_EEEENS_10ConnectionERKN5boost8functionIFvT_EEE[_ZN15message_filters12SimpleFilterIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEE16registerCallbackIRKN3ros12MessageEventIKS4_EEEENS_10ConnectionERKN5boost8functionIFvT_EEE]+0x310): referencia a `message_filters::Connection::Connection(boost::function<void ()> const&)' sin definir
CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/src/prueba.cpp.o: En la función `message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >::registerCallback<ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>(boost::function<void (ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&)':
prueba.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SimpleFilterIN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_ISaIvEEEE16registerCallbackIRKN3ros12MessageEventIKS4_EEEENS_10ConnectionERKN5boost8functionIFvT_EEE[_ZN15message_filters12SimpleFilterIN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_ISaIvEEEE16registerCallbackIRKN3ros12MessageEventIKS4_EEEENS_10ConnectionERKN5boost8functionIFvT_EEE]+0x310): referencia a `message_filters::Connection::Connection(boost::function<void ()> const&)' sin definir
CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/src/prueba.cpp.o: En la función `void message_filters::Synchronizer<message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::connectInput<message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType> >(message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >&, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&, message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>&)':
prueba.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SynchronizerINS_13sync_policies9ExactTimeIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_IS5_EENS_8NullTypeESA_SA_SA_SA_SA_SA_EEE12connectInputINS_10SubscriberIS6_EENSE_IS9_EENS_10NullFilterISA_EESI_SI_SI_SI_SI_SI_EEvRT_RT0_RT1_RT2_RT3_RT4_RT5_RT6_RT7_[_ZN15message_filters12SynchronizerINS_13sync_policies9ExactTimeIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_IS5_EENS_8NullTypeESA_SA_SA_SA_SA_SA_EEE12connectInputINS_10SubscriberIS6_EENSE_IS9_EENS_10NullFilterISA_EESI_SI_SI_SI_SI_SI_EEvRT_RT0_RT1_RT2_RT3_RT4_RT5_RT6_RT7_]+0x48): referencia a `message_filters::Connection::disconnect()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gps_pos/CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/build.make:116: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo '/home/juan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gps_pos/prueba'
make[2]: *** [/home/juan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gps_pos/prueba] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/juan/catkin_ws/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:892: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'gps_pos/CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/all'
make[1]: *** [gps_pos/CMakeFiles/prueba.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/juan/catkin_ws/build'
Makefile:141: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'all'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

please, don't have Idea, what I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340810/hi,--i-want-to-use-the-message-filter-in-this-example-,-i-tried-to-register-callback-from-a-class-member-function-as-in-the-following-code:/) by [Juan Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/50383/juan-carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml are properly configured?
I've tried compiling your code and it went completely fine (using "catkin build" command, ROS Kinetic).

In package.xml you should have "depend" fields for all needed packages.

My CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(message_filtering)
    
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_filters
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)


catkin_package(
)

## Build ##

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 add_executable(filtering src/filtering.cpp)

 target_link_libraries(filtering
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

---

Originally posted by [Nikodem](https://answers.ros.org/users/29718/nikodem/) with karma: 61 on 2019-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/50383/juan-carlos/) on 2020-01-03**:
Thanks you!, you are correct, forgot the nav_msgs in the CMakelist, thaks